# Show that $\left(1+\frac xk\right)^k$ is monotonically increasing

Tags: inequality

**Note: I don't want to get the full solution, but only a hint.**

I have to show that for $x \in [0, \infty)$, the sequence $\left(1+\frac xk\right)^k$ is monotonically increasing. We were already given the hint that we could use the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, but I don't see how to apply it yet.

I tried to do it by induction. While the case $k = 1$ works easily, I don't know how to start further from here. I already tried to use the definition of the binomial theorem, but it didn't lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Apply AM - GM inequality with $m > k$ to:

$$\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^{k/m} =\left(\frac{k+x}{k}\right)^{k/m} = \left[\left(\frac{k+x}{k}\right)^k \right]^{1/m} \\= \left[\underbrace{\frac{k+x}{k} \ldots \frac{k+x}{k}}_k \underbrace{1 \ldots 1}_{m-k}\right]^{1/m} \\ \leqslant \frac{1}{m}\left(k \frac{k+x}{k } + (m-k)(1) \right)$$

Comment: Still by induction? Or "directly"?

Comment: Directly.  Complete the arithmetic mean on the right side and see how it simplifies.

Comment: After that you do some exponentiation to both sides and you should be done

Comment: But how do you write an arbitrary $k$ as $n \over m$ with $m > n$, if I may ask? It seems like you used that here.

Comment: My $n$ is your $k$.  I'm showing for any $m$ greater than $n$ that $(1 + x/n)^n \leqslant (1+x/m)^m$.  The intermediate step is $(1+x/n)^{n/m} \leqslant (1 + x/m)$.

Comment: Try to show that the arithmetic mean on the right side of the AM GM inequality is $(1 + x/m)$.

Comment: But $k$ is a natural number, at the beginning of your answer, it seems like you wrote $k$ as $n \over m$. I don't understand that step.

Comment: No I'll change $n$ to $k$ above

Comment: Thanks for the change, but that wasn't my question, to be honest. Look: In the question, we only start with $k$ as an exponent, but now you write $k \over m$ with $m > k$. Why are you allowed to do so?

Comment: Im showing with AM GM that $(1+x/k)^{k/m} \leqslant (1 +k/m).$  I need an $m$ in the denominator of the exponent to apply AM GM which says $(a_1 a_2 \ldots a_m)^{1/m} \leqslant \frac{1}{m}(a_1 + a_2 + \ldots a_m)$.

Comment: See the step I inserted above. I'm allowed because we are taking $k$ fixed and considering any $m > k$ to show that $(1 +x/k)^{k/m} \leqslant (1 + x/m)$.  Then if you raise both sides to the power $m$ you will get your result $(1 +x/k)^{k} \leqslant (1 + x/m)^m$ for any $m > k$ -- showing that $(1+x/k)^k$ is increasing in $k$.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question, I didn't understand your motivation first since raising both sides to $m$ afterwards seems really sneaky to me. Do I still have to show that your last expression equals $(1$ $+$ $x \over m$)$?

Comment: Yes -- just some algebra. Pretty clear the expression inside parentheses reduces to $m + x$.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: One last question: Why do you write $1 ... 1$ $m-k$ times? And how do you conclude the last summand $m-k$ then?

Comment: The AM-GM inequality is $(a_1 a_2 \ldots a_m)^m \leqslant \frac{1}{m}(a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_m)$ . I added the $m-k$ $1$'s to obtain a full set of $m$ factors inside the $( \ldots)^{1/m}$ above enabling me to apply the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The AM-GM tells us that for non negative $\;a_n\;$ :

$$\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}n\ge\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n}$$

Let us apply this with

$$a_1=1\,,\,\,a_2=a_3=\ldots=a_{n+1}=1+\frac xn\;,\;\;\text{and then get :}$$

$$\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_{n+1}}{n+1}\ge\sqrt[n+1]{a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n+1}}\iff$$
$$\frac{1+\left(1+\frac xn\right)+\ldots+\left(1+\frac xn\right)}{n+1}\ge\sqrt[n+1]{1\cdot\left(1+\frac xn\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(1+\frac xn\right)}\stackrel{\text{raise to power}\;n+1 }\iff$$

$$\left(\frac{1+n\left(1+\frac xn\right)}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\ge\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\iff\left(1+\frac x{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\ge\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$

Comment: Beautiful approach. Thank you. By far the clearest exposition of this fact that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Expand it using the binomial theorem and try to look at the sum term by term. Create a sequence of each term (other than 1 obviously )and try to get that  it  increases for increasing $k $.

The sum will be $1+^kC_1(\frac xk) + ^kC_2 (\frac xk)^2 + ... ^kC_k (\frac xk)^k $.This could be written as $1+\sum_{r=1}^k {^kC_r(\frac xk)^r}$ Now consider the sequence $^kC_r(\frac 1k)^r$ and try to prove that this sequence is increasing for increasing $k$ for any $r >=1$. This will prove that each term of the sum increases thus implying the sum increases .

One way to prove that the sequence $ S = ^kC_r(\frac 1k)^r$ increase is to calculate the ratio $S (k+1)/S (k) $ and prove that is greater than or equal to 1 for all $k $.

Answer (score 0):

For $x=0$ the function is constant, so we can assume $x>0$.

Consider
$$
f(t)=\frac{\log(1+xt)}{t}
$$
for $t>0$. Then
$$
f'(t)=\frac{t\frac{x}{1+xt}-\log(1+xt)}{t^2}=
\frac{xt-(1+xt)\log(1+xt)}{t^2(1+xt)}
$$
Now our task is proving that, for $u>0$,
$$
g(u)=u-(1+u)\log(1+u)<0
$$
We indeed have $g(0)=0$ and
$$
g'(u)=1-\log(1+u)-1=-\log(1+u)
$$

Put together the pieces and conclude.