# Proof verification of $\{x_n\} = \left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right)^n$ is an increasing sequence.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, inequality, monotone-functions

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and:
>   $$
> x_n = \left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right)^n
> $$
>   Show that $\{x_n\}$ is an increasing sequence.

$\Box$ Consider ratio test of two consequent terms $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$:
$$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{\left(1 + {1\over 2n + 2}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right)^n} 
= \frac{\left(1 + {1\over 2n + 2}\right)^{n}}{\left(1 + {1\over 2n}\right)^n} \cdot\left(1 + {1\over 2n + 2}\right) = \\
= \left(\frac{2n(2n+3)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\right)^n \cdot\left(1 + {1\over 2n + 2}\right)
$$

We are done in case this product is greater than $1$.

Denote:
$$
P^n = \left(\frac{2n(2n+3)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\right)^n = \left(\frac{4n^2 + 6n}{4n^2 + 6n+2}\right)^n
$$

Split $P$ into partial fractions:
$$
P^n = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{2}{2n+1}\right)^n = \left(1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)(2n+1)}\right)^n
$$

Since $\frac{-1}{(n+1)(2n+1)} > -1$ we may apply Bernoulli's:
$$
P^n \ge 1 - \frac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}
$$

Thus:

$$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \ge \left(1 - \frac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}\right)\cdot\left(1+ \frac{1}{2n+2}\right) = \frac{2n^2 + 2n +1}{2n^2+3n+1} \cdot \frac{2n+3}{2n+2} = \\
= \frac{4 n^3 + 10 n^2 + 8 n + 3}{4 n^3 + 10 n^2 + 8 n + 2}
$$

From here it's clear that:

$$
{x_{n+1}\over x_n} > 1
$$

This completes the proof that $x_n$ is monotonically increasing. ${\blacksquare}$

Is this a valid proof? Also I would appreciate any simpler methods to show that.

Comment: Alternatively: Show (more, namely) that $(x_n^2)$ is increasing by using copy+paste from the grandpa' of the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b_n=(1+1/n)^n$ is [increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052328/show-that-left1-frac-xk-rightk-is-monotonically-increasing?rq=1). Your sequence is $x_n=\sqrt{b_{2n}}$, so it is increasing.

Comment: Oh god, that's so obvious. How haven't i thought of it in this way. Thank you!